# FileReader.readAsDataURL not working in react native 0.57

Tags: react-native, filereader

I need to parse an image that receive from a fetch request into an base64 string. When I as using RN 0.55.4 my code worked properly, but after upgrading to RN0.57  it didn't worked anymore.
I've logged my base64 string after upgrade, and I get:

```
IMAGE64 data:application/octet-stream;base64,77+977+977+977+9AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...(a bunch of "A"s)
```

Below is the code

```
    const fileReaderInstance = new FileReader()
       fileReaderInstance.readAsDataURL(response)
        fileReaderInstance.onload = () => {
       //result is always something like -- data:application/octet-
     //stream;base64,77+9UE5HDQoaCgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//`enter code here`AAAAAAAAAAA... (thousands of As)
             console.log(fileReaderInstance.result)

   }
```